# At what point in the Form Load are the Controls created in C# and Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, vb6, form-load

I am migrating a project written in Visual Basic to C#.

During the Load of a Form in VB I execute a function that uses the Controls of said Form and it works correctly.

However, when running the same function during Form Load in C#, the function does not work because it finds 0 Controls. So at what point are Controls created and assigned in VB and C#?

Code in Visual Basic:

New Form

```
Set Abertura(MiTag) = New aFrmAberturas
        Case 32, 4, 7, 28 ' "VIDRIOS" '"ACRÍLICOS" '"CIEGOS", 28 '"TELA MOSQUITERA"
            Set Abertura(MiTag) = New aFrmManualVi
```

My function during the Form Load

```
If Abertura(MiTag).LblRev1(1) = "Tela Mosquit" Then
   .inter1(1, MHA) = "Vidrio Simple"
     cambio = True
 End If
```

Controls.Count at the IF

```
?aModule1.Abertura(MiTag).Count  165
```

Code in C#

New Form

```
aModule1.Abertura[aModule1.MiTag] = new aFrmAberturas();                        
                    break;
                case 32 : case 4 : case 7 : case 28 :  // "VIDRIOS" '"ACRÍLICOS" '"CIEGOS", 28 '"TELA MOSQUITERA" 
                    aModule1.Abertura[aModule1.MiTag] = new aFrmManualVi();
```

My function during the Form Load

```
if (Convert.ToString(((dynamic) aModule1.Abertura[aModule1.MiTag])._LblRev1_) == "Tela Mosquit")
            {
                aModule1.Vars[aModule1.MiTag].Inter1[1, aModule1.MHA] = "Vidrio Simple";
                cambio = true;
            }
```

Controls.Count at the IF

```
aModule1.Abertura[aModule1.MiTag].Controls.Count 0
```

[VB: Here is the Form's declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INGCm.png)

[VB: This is my Function during the Form Load, and the Form's Controls.Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtiXg.png)

[C#: Here is the Form's declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqOEK.png)

[C#: This is my Function during the Form Load, and the Form's Controls.Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuaUm.png)

Comment: No idea about C++ but the sequence of events while creating a VB6 form is [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-life-cycle-of-vb6-forms/).

Comment: How was the migration done? Manually or with a code conversion tool?

Comment: Whit a conversion tool, Using Mobilize exactly

Comment: Look in the FormName.Designer.cs file - you should be able to see exactly where all the controls are being initialized etc. You may want to take a sample of that and add it to the question.